# Comparing 2 columns in Excel to see "Next High" using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to using VBA code and want to try implementing it in a hypothetical problem I am currently working on. I want to be able to compare 2 columns to see if they have similar numbers, and the first instance of a dissimilar number will become the "Next High." For example:

```
Client  Market
90      87  
92      91.25  
95      92  
95.5    93.5  
        95  
        95.5  

Next High:
```

Starting from the bottom of the list, the VBA macro should see if the Market and Client side have the same numbers. The first instance of a number that is on the Market side and not on the client side should be the "Next High". For example, in the above list, 95.5 is on the Market and Client side, and so is 95. Because the next number above 95 on the Market side is 93.5, and this is a higher number than the next number on the Client side(92), this becomes the "Next High."

I would appreciaite some direction with the VBA code! I will eleborate if this is confusing, thank you!

Comment: First, I would get the total number of rows in the Client and Market columns.  Then I would loop from the last value in the Market column to the first value in the Market column while searching the Client column to see if it contains the same value.  Once this returns false I would have the "Next High" value.  This assumes that the columns are arranged in ascending order.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me an example code? I just started learning VBA.

Answer (score 0):

See the attached code and review it.  I hope that this will help you get started and allow you to ask any specific questions that you may have.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

' This sub assumes that the columns are in ascending order already
Sub nextHigh()

' declaring variables before using them
Dim lastRowClient As Long
Dim lastRowMarket As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim testValue As String
Dim nextHigh As Double
Dim checkValue As String
Dim valueFound As Boolean

' initializing variables to a known value
lastRowClient = 0
lastRowMarket = 0
i = 0
j = 0
testValue = ""
nextHigh = 0
checkValue = ""
valueFound = False

' gets the last row of column 1
   With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRowClient = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowMarket = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

' for loop to iterate over column 2. note that you can specify the step value and change it from the default of +1
For i = lastRowMarket To 2 Step -1

    testValue = Cells(i, 2).value

    ' this loop iterates to check the found value against column 1
    For j = lastRowClient To 2 Step -1

    checkValue = Cells(j, 1).value

        ' actual check
        If testValue = checkValue Then

            'value was found and therefore is not "NextHigh"
            valueFound = True
            Exit For ' value was found so stop searching

        Else

            'value was notfound and therefore is "NextHigh"
            valueFound = False

        End If

    Next j

    If Not valueFound Then

        ' print out value to next column
        Cells(2, 3).value = testValue
        Exit Sub    'exits sub to avoid excessive looping

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Program output:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This code is a great starting point for me to really understand the syntax of VBA. For some reason though, when I ran your code my output was 95.5.

Comment: I will look into this. I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: I would suggest that you run through programs with "Step Into" with the default shortcut F8 so that you can see what is actually happening.

Comment: I had originally assumed that the issue was with floating point error but I tried to convert the values to strings and cannot get that to work again either. It might take me a bit to figure this out.

Comment: No worries, take your time! I am currently trying to solve the issue on my own as well. I really appreciaite your help!

Comment: I think the floating point error was a valid problem. Now I am just working out my own flawed logic in the for loops

Comment: @oddtimesigs okay. I have updated it again. hopefully for the last time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to use VBA for this? There's a fairly simple formula you could use instead.  Using your provided example data, this formula returns the correct result:

```
=MAX(INDEX((COUNTIF(A2:B7,A2:B7)=1)*A2:B7,))
```